# Yappi ModuleNotFoundError even after installation

Tags: python, pipenv, yappi

I have installed yappi successfully but still I'm getting ModuleNotFoundError while importing yappi in the same shell:

```
((python) ) soumeng78@linux-16 $ pipenv install  git+https://github.com/sumerc/yappi#egg=yappi
Installing git+https://github.com/sumerc/yappi#egg=yappi...
Adding yappi to Pipfile's [packages]...
âœ” Installation Succeeded
Pipfile.lock (db4242) out of date, updating to (b482eb)...
Locking [dev-packages] dependencies...
Locking [packages] dependencies...
Building requirements...
Resolving dependencies...
âœ” Success!
Updated Pipfile.lock (b482eb)!
Installing dependencies from Pipfile.lock (b482eb)...
  ðŸ   â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰â–‰ 0/0 â€” 00:00:00

((python) ) soumeng78@linux-16 $ python
Python 3.9.6 (default, Jan  4 2022, 00:31:29)
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import yappi

----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<stdin> 1 <module>
1

ModuleNotFoundError:
No module named 'yappi'
```

Any idea how to make it work? I want to use yappi for profiling a function.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the old environment and recreating the environment solved the problem. It seems like some issue with pipenv.

When I tried same pip install in conda virtual environment on Windows, I get below issue - seems some issue with the package:

```
Collecting yappi
  Using cached yappi-1.3.3.tar.gz (58 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... done
Building wheels for collected packages: yappi
  Building wheel for yappi (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × python setup.py bdist_wheel did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [9 lines of output]
      running bdist_wheel
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      copying yappi\yappi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      running build_ext
      building '_yappi' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for yappi
  Running setup.py clean for yappi
Failed to build yappi
Installing collected packages: yappi
  Running setup.py install for yappi ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Running setup.py install for yappi did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [11 lines of output]
      running install
      C:\Users\soumen\Miniconda3\envs\kubeflow-pipeline\lib\site-packages\setuptools\command\install.py:34: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
        warnings.warn(
      running build
      running build_py
      creating build
      creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      copying yappi\yappi.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.8
      running build_ext
      building '_yappi' extension
      error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools": https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
      [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: legacy-install-failure

× Encountered error while trying to install package.
╰─> yappi
```